# Disabled JS, Can't See Text Content Wordpress Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Having a really annoying problem here, and I have no clue what it could be right now. A website I built for someone works just fine with javascript enabled, but when it's disabled, almost all of the images and text are not visible on the entire site.

The kicker, is that all of the sections of the page are still there, but just invisible to the viewer. If you use the browser inspector you can see all of the stuff is there in the html and what not.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the content but not the images when i turn off Javascript.

I notice in the body tag there's a class of "layzr-loading-on" - so looked that up and found this: http://callmecavs.com/layzr.js/

I notice that the images in the demo on that site don't load when javascript is turned off either so i assume they haven't got a fallback to display images when javascript is turned off.

This library could be loaded manually by a plugin, or might be part of your theme or might be part of a cacheing plugin.

(added the following into the answer for anyone else who has the issue)
Because your theme adds an html class of "no-js" when js is turned off, you could try a style like:

.no-js .full-width-wrap {opacity: 1;}

That will probably sort you out as a fallback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am going to check into this today.

Comment: I notice that the content is hidden by a class in main.min.css 
.full-width-wrap { opacity: 0;} - which i assume is set to opacity: 1 when js is turned on.

Because your theme adds an html class of "no-js" when js is turned off, you could try a style like:
.no-js .full-width-wrap {opacity: 1;}
That will probably sort you out as a fallback.

Comment: This was the ticket, thanks a lot for that find, that is epic. All of the content is now visible even with js disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the visual builders like Visual Composer assume JS is enabled and they don't provide any fallback. If you set your elements and images to animate it, they start hidden and then rely on JS to appear. Without JS, they simply stay hidden/invisible.

Your only options are: (a) assume your users have JS enabled and the heck with everyone else, or (b) ditch the visual builder and build your own animations with better checking.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yeah, it's pretty crappy that they don't make that pretty well known. Going to look into it today.